# (intermediate value).on is not a function

Tags: jquery

estoy usando un script para subir imagenes directamente a imgur el cuál es https://github.com/carry0987/Imgur-Upload y me funcionaba bien con jquery 1.8 pero lo actualicé a  jQuery v3.3.1 y me da este error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).on is not a function
    at Imgur.createDragZone (imgur.js:84)
    at Imgur.run (imgur.js:161)
    at new Imgur (imgur.js:32)
    at upload.js:10
```

El código de esa linea 84 es:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.info, function (zone) {
zone.appendChild(p1);
zone.appendChild(p2);
}.on(this));
```

Comment: si vas a su repo y miras el fichero `upload.js` verás que se ha cambiado el `on` por `bind`. Quizá tienes una versión vieja de imgur

Comment: Era eso, cambié todos los .on por .bind y solucionado. Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada. Mejor bájate la última versión por si hay mas cambios